# Dynamically building independent object trees with CDI

Tags: cdi

I'm wondering how to use CDI to build multiple independent objects trees representing the same type of data. Here is an example:

I have a Car, in which I want to inject GearShift and Engine.
I also want to inject Engine in GearShift
This Car + GearShift + Engine is my tree.

If I want to have several cars at the same time, what would be the best way to do this using CDI?
I would expect to be able to define a kind of scope or a qualifier for each tree.
But CDI scopes and qualifiers are defined statically, while the number of cars is dynamic.

As an additional requirement, I would like to inject another dependency that would be shared between cars.
For example, all cars would share the same Road for their whole lifetime (couldn't find something else that makes more sense).
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think CDI is for inject object that is hard to create, like an EntityManager. It is simpler that you use aggregate your GearShift, Engine to your Car. Those object is POJO and maybe use `new` to create.

Comment: I would agree for DTOs. But for objects that have a behaviour (and that you may want to mock for example), I believe it's good practice to avoid creating them with the `new` operator

Answer (score 0):

I am no sure if I understand you properly, but I think you can, at least, use Session Scope, because you could create several Sessions with different Ids. For every Session you will have own Session Map.
In that way you can manage separate set of Cars Objects.

If you use Weld as CDI your implementation, you can use a BoundSessionContext  which can be bound to any Map. The context is automatically attached to the map on activation, and detached when invalidate() is called.